# send errors to "/login/errors" when logging fails instead of going to the path "/user_sessions"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, authlogic, rename

I am building an app with ruby on rails 3.1.
I have a login form correctly displayed at the url "/login". When an error occurs, I would like it to go to "login/errors" instead of "/user_sessions".

For information I am using [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)

The model used is called "user_session".

**in route.rb:**

```
resources :user_sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new'
root :to => redirect("/login")
```

**in user_sessions_controller.rb:**

```
    def new
      @user_session = UserSession.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
      end
    end

    def create
      @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user_session.save
          user = User.first(:conditions => {:email=> @user_session.email})
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'teams', :action => 'show', :id => user.team_id }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
        end
      end
    end
```

I have tried different things without success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

1. `match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', as: :login_page`
2. `redirect_to login_page_path` if saving was fail.

Comment: That's also the first thing I tried. it redirect properly to the login page but it doesnt pass the errors contained in @user_session. So I come back on the same page without any information to help.